# Is Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] reliable enough?

Tags: asp.net, ip-address, request.servervariables

Currently I am using Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] to get the IP from the client.

What guarantees I get when calling this Method. Or should I look in other ServerVariables as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Found some really neat information on retrieving the client's IP address here.](http://thepcspy.com/read/getting_the_real_ip_of_your_users/)

Essentially, you should probably also pay attention to the `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR")` as well.  This helps to identify the actual IP address if the end user is going through a proxy whereas the `REMOTE_ADDR` attribute would be the address of the proxy...unless it is an anonymous proxy in which case, you would still just get the proxy address.